# Configure Kafka Streams application to use Confluent Schema Registry

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I have a Kafka Streams java application which processes an Avro Kafka Topic, makes some changes in the data and sink the processed result in Avro into another Topic.

For this purpose, I'm using the Avro GenericRecord Serde, so I can deserialize each record, modify the fields I want and then serialize it again into Avro.

This is the Serde declaration, **configured to use the Schema Registry *http://localhost:8082***:

```
Map<String, String> serdeConfig;
serdeConfig = Collections.singletonMap("schema.registry.url","http://localhost:8082");
Serde<GenericRecord> keyGenericAvroSerde = new GenericAvroSerde();
Serde<GenericRecord> valueGenericAvroSerde = new GenericAvroSerde();
keyGenericAvroSerde.configure(serdeConfig, true);
valueGenericAvroSerde.configure(serdeConfig, false);
```

The result is sinked into a destination topic using the serde configured abobe:

```
//Process Stream
ObfuscateTopicProcessor obfuscateTopicProcessor = new ObfuscateTopicProcessor(environment, appName);
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
obfuscateTopicProcessor.convert(builder, topics, fieldList)
        .to((k, v, r) -> r.topic() + topicSufix, Produced.with(keyGenericAvroSerde, valueGenericAvroSerde));
//Run Stream
Topology topology = builder.build();
KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, props);
```

**The problem: When I run the application it works just fine, but it generates the new processed topic schema in the Schema-Registry *http://localhost:8081*.**

This is the log of the application, it should create the new topic schema in http://localhost:8082:

```
[2019-12-10 10:46:51,190] [INFO] KafkaAvroSerializerConfig values:
    bearer.auth.token = [hidden]
    schema.registry.url = [http://localhost:8082]
    basic.auth.user.info = [hidden]
    auto.register.schemas = true
    max.schemas.per.subject = 1000
    basic.auth.credentials.source = URL
    schema.registry.basic.auth.user.info = [hidden]
    bearer.auth.credentials.source = STATIC_TOKEN
    value.subject.name.strategy = class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicNameStrategy
    key.subject.name.strategy = class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicNameStrategy  (io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializerConfig)
```

Am I missing any important configuration parameter?

Comment: What do you mean that it creates it at 8081? Are you running two registries?

Comment: Yes, we are running two instances of schema registry in the same server (they are needed for MirrorMaker). Thanks for the reply.

Comment: MirrorMaker can use 8082 as well... And you should not run two master registries against the same Kafka cluster. In any case, 8081 is the default, so one of your serdes is misconfigured and I'm betting it's in the logs somewhere for which one it is

Comment: And I say that because what you show here is correct https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/datatypes.html#avro

Comment: MirrorMaker should actually just use ByteArraySerializer. There's no real reason it needs to care about the content of the topic